# How to lazy evaluate and execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have following situation:
I have 86 charts (ChartsJS) divided into three categories. I am using JQueryUI Tabs to display each category one at the time in separate tab. The thing is, that due to to large amount of javascript embedded into the page, page load time is over 7 seconds in which JS parsing and execution takes over 5.2 of that time (measured using google chrome).

I am wondering is there a way to lazy evaluate those JavaScript parts that renders elements that are not  yet presented to the user (not on currently open tab). Please notice, that I would like not only to execute given script on tab change (this is obvious and easy to do) but to evaluate required script on demand at some given point of time after page load.

EDIT: 
I need to clarify that my JS **is dynamically generated** thus asyncload from file is not an option. This could be a design flaw on my side.

Here is a timeline from chrome:
[image]

Comment: The tab plugin has events you can hook to. Therefore you can know which charts are currently visible and only load those ones.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is true and handling that event is not a problem. The problem is how to evaluate (first time load) js and execute on the fly without using file load.

Comment: I don't see how that would be a problem? Use the callback of the AJAX request to intialise the charts after they've been appended to the DOM

Comment: Actually it's a design flaw like you've said in your edit...

Comment: Well browser evaluates all the JS onload. I need to prevent it and trigger it on demand. How?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Any proper design clues?

Comment: (based on edit: Instead of dynamically generating your JS, why not have a simple API that returns data, and have your JS request and use that data to the same effect?)

Comment: @Antoniossss Code generation could be done either server-side or during build-time, for example

Comment: This done on server side - rendered along with page. What i would like is to include that generated code into page (in form of comment or non script tag or something) and force parsing it on demand (eg. by injecting that content into <script> tag on demand). The thing is, is this the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in a function definition is not executed until the function is called. hence you can wrap your tab specific code in functions and call them whenever you open that tab.

in order to run a chart in `chartjs` you need to write the following:

```
var myChart = new Chart(SELECTOR, {...})
```

hence only call new Chart on your active selectors

```
//Global Configs
Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = 'single';

function onTabOne() {
    var myChart = new Chart(SELECTOR, {...})
}
function onTabTwo() {
    var pieChart = new Chart(SELECTOR, {...})
}
```

**NOTE**
evaluation of javascript is super fast and is not heavy on machine, its basically hoisting and memory allocation for variables, you should not worry about lazy evaluation, and there is no direct way. but execution is where the heavy work takes place, and you can delay execution by wrapping things in function definitions.

there are hacky ways to get lazy evaluation, such as putting javascript in strings and using `eval` whenever you want to evaluate and execute the code, but i dont recommend using eval at all. 
 and there is no real need to do it.

Comment: Sure, but the code you have written will be parsed - as there is a lot of JS, the parsing itself takes 2.6 seconds. I want to avoid that as well

Comment: hmm, then i believe you should optimize your code instead of finding a way to "lazy parse" it. what do you mean dynamically generated?

 Chrome parses async and deferred scripts on a separate thread as soon as the download has begun. This means that parsing can complete just milliseconds after the download has finished, and results in pages loading as much as 10% faster.